# What will happen if the derivative of a piecewise function is continuous?

Tags: derivatives, continuity

**Question:**

> Let f(x)is a piecewise function and
> $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> x^\alpha \cdot \cos{\frac{1}{x^\beta}}, &x>0 \\
> 0, &x \leq 0
> \end{cases}$$
> If $f'(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$, then the range of $\alpha-\beta$ is?

**And the answer is:**

> $\alpha - \beta >1$

**What I have:**
$f'(0)$ exist
$\Leftrightarrow$ $f'_{-}(0)=f'_{+}(0)$
$\Leftrightarrow$ $0=\lim\limits_{h\to0^-}\frac{0-0}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to0^-}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=f'_{-}(0)  
f'_{-}(0)=f'_{+}(0)=\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}\frac{h^\alpha \cdot \cos{\frac{1}{h^\beta}}-0}{h}=\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}h^{\alpha-1} \cdot \cos{\frac{1}{h^\beta}}$
$\Leftrightarrow$ $\alpha-1>0$

**What is confusing me:**

1. Is following statement right?

   - $f'(x_0)$ exist   $\Leftrightarrow$   $f'_{-}(x_0)=f'_{+}(x_0)$
   - $f(x)$ is countinuous at the point $x=x_0$  $\Leftrightarrow$   $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^-}f(x)$
   - But $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f'(x) \neq f'_+(x_0)$
2. If 1. is correct, does it means that derivative formulas does not apply to the derivative of boundary points of piecewise functions? It seems true since I found that, in the function above:

   - *By definition:* $f'_+(0)=\lim\limits_{h\to0^+}h^{\alpha-1} \cdot \cos{\frac{1}{h^\beta}}$
   - *By derivative formulas:* $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f'(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to0^+} \alpha x^{\alpha-1}\cos{\frac{1}{x^\beta}}+\beta x^{\alpha-\beta-1}\sin{\frac{1}{x^{\beta}}}$
3. If 2. is correct, then why? I know that if $f(x)$ is derivable at $x=x_0$, then $f(x)$ is at least continuous in some $U(x_0, \delta)$. Then:

   - $f'_+(x_0)$ means, $f(x)$ is continuous in some $U(x_0, \delta)$, and thus we can obtain the instantaneous rate of change of $f(x)$ at $x=x_0$. If the we obtain the value from right, then this rate is so called $f'_+(x_0)$
   - $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}f'(x)$ means, in some $U(x_0, \delta)$, all the points $(x,f'(x))$ exist, and form a function *s.t.* $f'(x)$. When approching to $x_0$ from right, the function value is so called $\lim\limits_{x\to x_0^+}f'(x)$.
     Is the statement above right? But if so, it seems like when $f'(x)$ is continuous, the two angles of above respective statements are exactly identical, isn't it? Additionally, if $f'(x)$ exist in some $U(x_0,\delta)$ and $f'(x_0)$ exists, then $f'(x)$ is continuous. (Since if not, either $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f'(x) \neq f'(x_0)$ or $\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}f'(x) \neq f'(x_0)$, but both yield the contridiction to $f'(x_0)$ exists, i.e. $f'_-(x_0)=f'_+(x_0)$).  Then $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}f'(x) = f'_+(x_0)$ exist all the time if f'(x) exist in some $U(x_0,\delta)$?